# Somewhat inappropriate|distasteful user name - what can be done?

Tags: discussion

Although I'm pretty liberal about most things, a new user, [rectumrectifier](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/111822/rectumrectifier), has a name which is a little childish, if not mildly pornographic.

How is this approached by the admins on AskDifferent? Is there a standard for usernames?

Comment: see this Meta Stack Exchange question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users

Comment: Maybe the questions and answers of this user matter rather than the user name. What would it be if you were not pretty liberal about most things?

Answer (score 2):

If you find that something about a user is offensive or inappropriate outside of any particular post, flag any post from that user with a custom flag.

There is more leeway with what is allowed in the [About Me section](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog) of a user's profile as this requires a click-through, however avatars and names are subject to removal if deemed inappropriate.

<sup>Related on Meta.SE: [Inappropriate username and/or gravatars.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147519/inappropriate-username-and-or-gravatars)</sup>